# How Call Sign_in method with Authentication Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In my code I write my registration code and after it i call sign_in method to return user with client , uid and access-token included in the header but when calling the sign_in , it returns the user object only and the header not included(uid,access-token,client)

```
  promoter = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if(promoter)
    render json: {message:"this email is already exist"} , status: 422
  else

     @promoter = Promoter.new(promoter_params)


     user = User.create(:email => params[:email],:password => params[:password],:user_role_id => 4)

    @promoter.user_id = user.id

    if @promoter.save 
      resource = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      puts(resource)
      if resource.valid_password?(params[:password])
        puts("user ok ")
        r = sign_in :user, resource
        render json: r,:methods => [:uid,:client] , status: 200
      end

    else
      render json: @promoter.errors , status: 422
    end
  end
```

the result is

```
"exception": "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `client' for #<User:0x00007f67d46df018>>",
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to call api

```
     puts "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
     params = {"email" => "test8@gmail.com", "password" => "12121212"}
     x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/auth/sign_in"), params)
     render json: x.body
```

but it also cannot render the header